# increase query performance in mysql

Tags: mysql, join, group-by

I have used this query

```
SELECT  COUNT(CASE WHEN C <= 1 THEN 1 END) AS nooffamiliesHavingcount1,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN C BETWEEN 2 AND 4 THEN 1 END) AS nooffamiliesHavingcountbetween2And4,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN C > 4 THEN 1 END) AS nooffamiliesHavingcountgreaterthan3
FROM    (   SELECT  COUNT(*) AS C
            FROM    user where user_id = (select user_id from location where location_id in(select location_id from country where state_name='STATE'))
            GROUP BY House_No
        ) t
```

> Here sub query returning approximately 10000 records .    The user
>   table has 10,00,000 records.    It is taking too much time.Then the
>   error it is saying is server gone away.    I am using mysql.

I searched from google.But no luck for me.

What changes i need to do for my tables.How i can execute this query successfully by 
   increasing the query performance.Please suggest me.Thanks in advance....

Comment: **You need to show us the table and index definitions.**  Diagnosing slow queries requires full table and index definitions, not just a description or paraphrase.  Maybe your tables are defined poorly.  Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly.  Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did.   Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell.  If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well.

Comment: We need to see the entire query.  It's not enough for you to paraphrase "Here another subquery".  Show us the entire code, all the table definitions and all the index definitions.

Comment: is there any way for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this query

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN C <= 1 THEN 1 END) AS nooffamiliesHavingcount1,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN C BETWEEN 2 AND 4 THEN 1 END) AS nooffamiliesHavingcountbetween2And4,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN C > 4 THEN 1 END) AS nooffamiliesHavingcountgreaterthan3
FROM  
  (SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS C
  FROM 
    user u,  
    location l, 
    country c 
  where 
    l.state_name='STATE' AND 
    l.some_other_column_id= 4 AND  <------- Add your condition
    c.location_id = l.location_id AND 
    u.user_id = l.user_id 
  GROUP BY 
    u.House_No) t
```

Use proper joins as it will be easy to understand..

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN C <= 1 THEN 1 END) AS nooffamiliesHavingcount1,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN C BETWEEN 2 AND 4 THEN 1 END) AS nooffamiliesHavingcountbetween2And4,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN C > 4 THEN 1 END) AS nooffamiliesHavingcountgreaterthan3
FROM  
  (SELECT 
    COUNT(*) AS C
  FROM 
    user u
  INNER JOIN  
    location l
  ON 
    l.state_name='STATE' AND 
    l.some_other_column_id= 4   <------- Add your condition
    u.user_id = l.user_id 
  INNER JOIN
    country c 
  ON 
    c.location_id = l.location_id 
  GROUP BY 
    u.House_No) t
```

**EDITED**

In most cases JOINs are faster than sub-queries and it is very rare for a sub-query to be faster. 
I accept using subquery is more logical and easy to understand but when it comes about performance it is not as good as joins. 
If you are using joins your db will optimize your query on its own which is not in the case of subquery.
Try using explain for both of your query and you will get clear idea how the query executes.

Hope this helps...

Comment: what is the difference between the queries used by me and u.Can u explain please

Comment: you are replaced subquery by using joins .What is the difference subquery and joins

Comment: Should have added the explanation from first... Check the edit.. Hope it helps...

Comment: i have another question.Can u help me now

Comment: actually my sub query have condition based on id not name

Comment: if i specified those ids directly in the query then it is ok.If i get those ids from another sub query i am facing the same problem

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, you want to replace the `where state_name='STATE'` to some `id`? If yes than you just get the id's from the table by adding join to that table.

Comment: my sub query is  select location_id from location where some_other_column_id= 4

Comment: Check the edit..  It would be better if you use second query which follows the `ANSI` convention...

Comment: performance wise is it good to write sub queries otherwise i need to write 2 queries.

Comment: actually i posted some code in sub query that is some little bit different with what i have.So i got some confusion

Comment: As I have mentioned in the explanation if the table is too large than using subquery will good as we filter out useless data on which processing takes place. So it depends on the situation, so better you check with both the approach. The edit that I made in answer is not working ?

Comment: i will post my original query.I am confusing with this.Can u change that query

Comment: it is very difficult to post here .I have more code.How i can post

Answer (score 1):

Can you try below:

SELECT  COUNT(CASE WHEN COUNT(*) <= 1 THEN 1 END) AS nooffamiliesHavingcount1,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN COUNT(*) BETWEEN 2 AND 4 THEN 1 END) AS nooffamiliesHavingcountbetween2And4,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 4 THEN 1 END) AS nooffamiliesHavingcountgreaterthan3
FROM User user 
Inner JOIN
(select user_id from location loc
Inner Join country con
on loc.location_id =con.location_id   where state_name='STATE' )as temp

on user.user_id =temp.user_id group by House_No

Comment: +1 for you .it is also useful for me.But takes some time to understand.

Comment: actually i posted some code in sub query that is some little bit different with what i have.So i got some confusion